# Colour change error in skvideo FFmpeg writer

Tags: python, ffmpeg

When I am recording videos in skvideo with the following code

```
import skvideo.io

# open the webcam video stream
webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

print(cv2.__version__)

# open output video file stream
video = skvideo.io.FFmpegWriter("video.avi",{}, {"-q":"0", "-color_primaries": "3", "-color_trc": "1", "-colorspace": "1"})

# main loop
while True:
    # get the frame from the webcam
    stream_ok, frame = webcam.read()
    
    # if webcam stream is ok
    if stream_ok:
        # display current frame
        cv2.imshow('Webcam', frame)
        
        # write frame to the video file
        video.writeFrame(frame)

    # escape condition on Esc key pressed
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == 27: 
        break

# clean ups
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# release web camera stream
webcam.release()

# release video output file stream
video.close()
```

The colour of the picture is changing[image: Original]
**Original**

[image: Recording]
**Recording**

Can anyone tell me how can I fix it?
I have ffmpeg version git-2020-04-13-59e3a9a Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 9.3.1 (GCC) 20200328

Python version 3.9.6

Opencv version 4.5.4

Skvideo version 1.1.10

Comment: Looks like BGR versus RGB pixel format. Try adding `"-pix_fmt":"bgr24"`

Comment: Adding this didn't work

Comment: Place it in the first dictionary - replace `{}` with `{"-pix_fmt":"bgr24"}`

Comment: Now it worked. Thanks

Comment: I think you should add it as an answer below so that I can accept it as an answer.

Comment: It is too simple... Also, I am not sure it is the recommended solution.

Comment: Ok then. Thanks for the help